# Simple JavaScript Module "Loader"

Tags: javascript, modules

I have written a simple JS module "loader" (loader is in quotes because it doesn't actually load the files) that is designed to resolve simple dependencies between modules. It is heavily inspired by [module.js](https://github.com/lrsjng/modulejs) and takes some of it's design from it.

Here is the code itself:

```javascript
(function() {
  function create() {
    var definitions = {},
        instances = {};

    // Returns whether or not a module with the provided id is defined.
    var defined = function(id) {
      return definitions.hasOwnProperty(id);
    };

    // Define a module with the provided id and definition.
    var define = function(id, definition) {
      if(defined(id)) {
        throw new Error('module already defined: ' + id);
      }

      definitions[id] = definition;
    };

    // Undefine a module with the provided id.
    var undefine = function(id) {
      if (!defined(id)) {
        throw new Error('module not defined: ' + id);
      }

      delete definitions[id];
      delete instances[id];
    };

    // Require a module with the provided id.
    var require = function(id) {
      var stack = [];

      var internalRequire = function(id) {
        if(!defined(id)) {
          throw new Error('module not defined: ' + id);
        }

        // If we have already seen this id on the require stack, we've got
        // some form of cyclic dependency.
        if (stack.indexOf(id) !== -1 && stack.push(id)) {
          throw new Error('cyclic dependency: ' + stack.join(' -> '));
        } else {
          stack.push(id);
        }

        // If we already have an instance for this module, return it.
        if (instances.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
          return instances[id];
        } else if (typeof(definitions[id]) === 'function') {
          // Otherwise if our definition is a function, call it and pass the
          // require method to it.
          return instances[id] = definitions[id].call(null, internalRequire);
        } else {
          // Otherwise just return the definition itself (useful for objects
          // e.g. constants).
          return instances[id] = definitions[id];
        }
      };

      return internalRequire(id);
    };

    return {
      define: define,
      undefine: undefine,
      require: require
    };
  }

  window.module = create();
})();
```

And some example usage:

```javascript
module.define('person', function() {
  var Person = function(name) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
      value: name
    });
  };

  Person.prototype.speak = function(text) {
    return this.name + ': ' + text;
  };

  return Person;
});

module.define('main', function(require) {
  var Person = require('person');

  var jack = new Person('Jack'),
      rocky = new Person('Rocky');

  console.log(jack.speak('Hi Rocky!'));
  console.log(rocky.speak('Hi Jack!'));
});
```

I don't really have any "burning questions" about my code; I'd just like some feedback on what people think of it and whether anyone can see any improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names `define` and `defined` are too similar, which could lead to mistakes. I suggest renaming the latter to `isDefined`.

---

You could flatten some of the conditionals when all branches leave the block. For example:

```
// If we have already seen this id on the require stack, we've got
// some form of cyclic dependency.
if (stack.indexOf(id) !== -1 && stack.push(id)) {
  throw new Error('cyclic dependency: ' + stack.join(' -> '));
}
stack.push(id);

// If we already have an instance for this module, return it.
if (instances.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
  return instances[id];
}

if (typeof(definitions[id]) === 'function') {
  // Otherwise if our definition is a function, call it and pass the
  // require method to it.
  return instances[id] = definitions[id].call(null, internalRequire);
}

// Otherwise just return the definition itself (useful for objects
// e.g. constants).
return instances[id] = definitions[id];
```